# Should I capitalize the word "that" in a title?

Tags: capitalization, titles

Since the version of the word "***that***" might matter to the correct answer, I'll provide the actual title in question:

**Title**:  Existing Solutions ***that*** Didn't Work

If someone could explain the *why* of the answer, I would be appreciative.

**EDIT:**  It has been suggested that this is a duplicate, and that may be, in a sense.  However, the after reading the suggested prior question, I'm no closer to my answer.  I think it may have to do with my use of the word "***that***."  Perhaps it is incorrect?

Using these definitions of the word "***that***:"
I'm having trouble figuring out which definition of ***that*** matches my title.  Am I even using it correctly?  Perhaps I should use **which** instead:

**Possible Title**:  Existing Solutions ***which*** Didn't Work

If my original usage is incorrect, and I should use ***which***, then the answer is simple since ***which*** is always a pronoun or adjective, and those are both capitalized in a title.  However, I'm having difficulty understanding which part of speech ***that*** is in my original title.

Comment: The 'why' is simple: _convention_.

Comment: Please forgive my poor mechanical grasp of English.  I AM trying!

Comment: 'That' here is a relative pronoun. 'Which' would be equally grammatical but less punchy. Whether or not you capitalise a relative pronoun in a title is a matter of style rather than real rules. Many wouldn't.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Thank you for the very clear answer.  I now have two things to study that I did not before.  That is a good start :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Edwin commented, whether or not you capitalize a pronoun in a title is a matter of style, however, the main style guides do not differ on this point.

The **AP** convention is to capitalize all words with four or more letters.

The **APA Manual** also capitalizes all words with four or more letters as well as all "major words." Only "conjunctions, articles, and short prepositions are not considered major words" (APA Manual, 6th Ed., p. 101).

The **Chicago Manual of Style** does not base headline-style capitalization on word length. It calls for capitalization of "nouns, pronouns, verbs, adjectives, and some conjunctions" (excluding the conjunctions *and, but, for or* and *nor*). Prepositions and articles are always lowercase unless the preposition is part of a verb phrase (like "Look Up").

In short, you're safe to capitalize the words *that* and *which* in your title as they are both relative pronouns.

As a side note: in American English, the convention would be to use the word *that* in your title, as it qualifies as a [restrictive clause](http://www.grammarly.com/answers/questions/104-difference-between-that-and-which/).